# Twilio with c# asp.net webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, twilio

I am implementing simple Twilio service for sending sms using c#.

I want to receive the status of the message sent to any number, so I created Asp.Net WebAPI HTTP post method (status call back) and exposed to Twilio like  below. But every time I send message, this http post method is not receiving any and my Twilio trial account logging the below message

> You are receiving this email because your Twilio account has
>   encountered an error or warning and the On 1st error every day Alert
>   Trigger has fired. The most recent alert was:
>
> "11200 - HTTP retrieval failure"

The URL I used for the status call back is public domain and https.

Am I doing something wrong here ? Please help me.

Code

```
var message = twilio.SendMessage(
          "+14439173365", 
          "+1xxxxxxxx", 
          "Sample Twilio message",
          "https://www2.xxxx.com/webservices/Reminder/V1/WebAPI/Reminder/TwilioAPI/MessageStatusCallBack");
```

Comment: Are you able to make a `curl` request to your URL? Does it definitely work?

Comment: I am able to make curl request as well fiddler request.  But whenever I send xml request , api is failing but JSON format request is successful.  Twilio response will be TwilML , right ?

Comment: What do you mean that the API is failing but JSON format request works? Twilio will send you url encoded parameters in the POST body and expects you to return XML (TwiML). What is the code behind your status callback url?

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

Can you check the full list of possible causes and solutions for your error [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200)?

You can also see a non-trivial example of using the `StatusCallback` in this tutorial found here using [C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/eta-notifications/csharp/mvc#4

It can sometimes help to get these examples working and then make changes according to your application.

Hope this helps.